# Can a function execute differently when called from inside another function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following in jQuery:

```
function SelectAccounts() {
    if ($("#AccountID option[value='0000']").length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Administration/Accounts/GetOptions",
            data: { ac: $('#AccountID').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#AccountID').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    SelectProducts();
}

function SelectProducts() {
    if ($("#ProductID option[value='0000']").length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Administration/Products/GetOptions",
            data: { ac: $('#AccountID').val(),
                    pr: $('#ProductID').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ProductID').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the account changes I want the product list to change so I put SelectProducts(); at the bottom of that function. However I want it to do an ajax call even if the following is not true **if selectProducts() is called from within the selectAccounts() function**

```
$("#ProductID option[value='0000']").length > 0)
```

Is there an easy way I can do this. I think I'll have to pass in some parameter to the the seconf function but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why not just remove the `if`?  If you mean a different ajax call, why can't you use an `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable:

```
var force = false;
```

Change function to accept parameter:

```
function SelectProducts(force){

  if (force || $("#ProductID option[value='0000']").length > 0) {

    ...
  }
}
```

Then when calling the second function do:

```
SelectProducts(true);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This looks good. Do I have to declare the variable force. What if I don't declare that. Is there a way I can make it default to false such as function SelectProducts( force = false ) ?

Comment: It's a little less straightforward with JS than other languages: http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php

Comment: You don't need the `var force = false;` line, having `function SelectProducts(force)` is enough to declare the variable. If you call `SelectProducts()` without any parameters then `force` will be `undefined` which is falsy. Basically javascript will treat it like `SelectedProducts(force=undefined)` behind the scenes which will work just like `SelectProducts( force = false )` for you.